# Mutually orthogonal vectors in a complex vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, vectors

Consider a Matrix $A \in \mathbb C^{m \times n}$, $m<n$ which is build by vectors like
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
| & | & & | \\
\vec a_1 & \vec a_2 & \cdots & \vec a_n \\
|  & | & & | 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where every vector is written like
$$
\vec a_i = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1i}  \\
a_{2i} \\
\vdots \\
a_{mi}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
If I calculate the matrix product $A^\dagger A$ I find
$$
A^\dagger A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\langle \vec a_1 , \vec a_1 \rangle & \langle \vec a_1 , \vec a_2 \rangle & \cdots & \langle \vec a_1 , \vec a_n \rangle \\
\langle \vec a_2 , \vec a_1 \rangle & \langle \vec a_2 , \vec a_2 \rangle & \cdots & \langle \vec a_2 , \vec a_n \rangle \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\langle \vec a_n , \vec a_1 \rangle & \langle \vec a_n , \vec a_2 \rangle & \cdots & \langle \vec a_n , \vec a_n \rangle
\end{pmatrix}\
$$
where I use the standard scalar product
$$
\langle \vec a_i , \vec a_j \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^m a_{ki}^* a_{kj} 
$$

My question is: Is it possible to require $A^\dagger A \overset{!}{=} \mathbb 1$ ? This would imply that all vectors $\vec a_1,...,\vec a_n$ are mutually orthogonal. However, I am not sure if this is possible since $n>m$. Or is it possible because we deal with complex vectors?

Comment: Just to clarify: when you say you want $A^\dagger A \overset{!}{=} \mathbb 1$ do you want this to equal the identity matrix, or the matrix of all 1s?

Comment: What does the ! represent?

Comment: I want it to be the identity matrix. And the ! just means that I require that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible because you can't have a collection of $n$ orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{C}^m$ if $n > m$. Alternatively,

$$ \operatorname{rank}(A^{\dagger} A) \leq \min ( \operatorname{rank}(A^{\dagger}), \operatorname{rank}(A) ) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A) \leq m $$

since $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix with $m < n$ and in particular, we can't have $A^{\dagger} A = I_n$ as this would imply that $\operatorname{rank}(A^{\dagger} A) = n$.